# Import statement continues to fail

Tags: python-2.7, import

I need some help figuring out an import error.

Here is my directory structure for a python project.

```
├── files  
│   ├── dictionary_files  
│   │  
│   └── transcripts  
├── src  
│   ├── package1  
│   │   ├── adapt_dictionary.py  
│   │   ├── adapt_dictionary.pyc  
│   │   └── __init__.py  
│   ├── package2  
│   └── subtitle.py  
└── test  
    ├── logs  
    │   └── error_log_dict.txt  
    ├── test1.py  
    └── test2.py
```

Here's the problem. The file `test1.py` is a testing suite I wrote for `adapt_dictionary.py`. In `adapt_dictionary.py` I have a class called `D_bot`.

```
class D_bot:
    def __init__(self):
```

I'm trying to import this class into my `test1.py` file.

```
import sys
import import sys
sys.path.append("/home/andy/Documents/Projects/AI_Subs/src/package1")
from adapt_dictionary import D_Bot
```

The console yields `cannot import name D_Bot`. Not sure what's going on. I have tried a few things.

- ensure no circular dependencies (good on this)
- changing `PYTHONPATH` to point to the corresponding directory where the class lies
- messing with `sys.path`

My python path is given as follows in my `.bashrc` file.

```
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:/home/andy/Documents/Projects/AI_Subs/src/package1
```

Still no luck. I'm running python 2.7.6 and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, the `sys.path.append` line you wrote is wrong. If you want to import a file that is in a package you should add the directory where *the package* is contained and then import the file from the package:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/andy/Documents/Projects/AI_Subs/src")
from package1.adapt_dictionary import D_Bot
```

You may thing that adding `src/package1` and using `import adapt_dictionary` is equivalent to the above: **it is not**!

- If you have different `adapt_dictionary` files in your `PYTHONPATH` they may be imported instead of the one from the package
- Moreover in some cases it **does** matter whether the module is imported from the package or not (e.g. if you use the `pickle` module you must be consistent in your imports otherwise code breaks).

Moreover you are trying to fix the wrong error. The interpreter **does** import the `adapt_dictionary` module, but it cannot find the `D_bot` class. See:

```sh
$mkdir package1
$touch package1/__init__.py
$echo 'class X: pass' > package1/a.py
$echo 'from package1.a import X
> from package1.a import Y' > test1.py
$python test1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 2, in <module>
    from package1.a import Y
ImportError: cannot import name Y
$echo 'from package1.b import X' > test2.py
$python test2.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test2.py", line 1, in <module>
    from package1.b import X
ImportError: No module named b
```

Note how your error resembles the first one and not the second one?
And the first one occurs because `a.py` *exists* but does not contain an `Y` class.

You may have an `adapt_dictionary.py` module somewhere and the interpreter is importing that one instead or there may be some obsolete `.pyc` around.

Also, is `adapt_dictionary` the actual name of the module? I've seen many times people posting code with made up names when their actual files were called with the same name as a built-in file, in which case the `import`s prefer the built-in one to yours.

Try doing:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/andy/Documents/Projects/AI_Subs/src/package1")
import adapt_dictionary
print(adapt_dictionary.__file__)
```

to check which module got imported.

Comment: Yes. I realized my error was extremely trivial in that I was importing D_Bot, but the class was defined D_bot. Nonetheless, I gained some good insight on importing the package rather than the file itself so thank you! Actually, I gained some great insights on imports in general!